# Use Bitbucket Resources in another application

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am software engineering student and I have to create a new project for one of my courses.

I've designed my application solution which needs to use git as a backend service. it needs git basics operations such as create a user, grant accesses, manage ssh keys, commit, push and etc, so I tried to run a git server but I thought it will be a better solution if application uses a perfect service like bitbucket.

so my question is, can I use bitbucket resources for my application as backend service? and if the answer is yes , please tell my how can I do this and also can I use bitbucket resources for free?

thanks in advance,

best regards.

Comment: Why BitBucket? While BitBucket supports Git, it's mainly a Mercurial host. Wouldn't it be better to use something written for Git, like GitHub or Gitorious?

Comment: @IdanArye it doesn't matter what the service is, github, bitbucket or etc, I just want to use another service as a git server which has a good development team,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your own backend for testing, I'd suggest [SCM Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org/). It might not be as nearly as good as BitBucket, GitHub or Gitorious, but it's much, **much**, **MUCH** easier to install. Unless you need the more complex ALM features(like issue tracking or web GUI for code reviews) it should suffice your needs.

Comment: thanks, but as I told I don't want to run my own git server. I want to use another service

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitBucket. It support both for Git and Mercurial repositories. The service offering includes an issue tracker and wiki, as well as integration with a number of popular third-party services.

The great thing of BitBucket, compared with GitHub, is that it's *free* and you can create as many *private repos* as you want.

Comment: any documentation, tutorial which can help to find out how can I use bitbucket resources

Comment: @NimaGhaedsharafi To start on, check out [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial).